# Timeline.js how can i change the navigation to top

Tags: javascript, timeline.js

timelinejs what do i need to do in configuration file to show navigation on top.

They have the option in the site (http://timeline.knightlab.com/#make-step-3) but don't explain how you can do it if you don't use their generator.

Answer (score 0):

The Documentation indicates a property that you can set on the Options object called "timenav_position" with values "top" and "bottom".

See here:
http://timeline.knightlab.com/docs/options.html#timenav_position